# Create array from file_get_contents() value

Tags: php, arrays, file-get-contents

socallink.txt:

> "Facebook","Twitter","Twitter","google-plus","youtube","pinterest","instagram"

PHP:

```
$file = file_get_contents('./Temp/socallink.txt', true);
$a1 = array($file);
print_r($a1);
```

Result :

```
Array
(
    [0] => "Facebook","Twitter","Twitter","google-plus","youtube","pinterest","instagram"
)
```

Needed:

```
$a1['0']=facebook;
$a1['1']=Twitter;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This solves your problem :

```
$file = '"Facebook","Twitter","Twitter","googleplus","youtube","pinterest","instagram"'; // This is your file
```

First remove all the ".

```
$file = str_replace('"', '', $file);
```

Then explode at every ,

```
$array = explode(',',$file);
```

`var_dump($array)` gives :

```
array(7) {
  [0]=>
  string(8) "Facebook"
  [1]=>
  string(7) "Twitter"
  [2]=>
  string(7) "Twitter"
  [3]=>
  string(11) "google-plus"
  [4]=>
  string(7) "youtube"
  [5]=>
  string(9) "pinterest"
  [6]=>
  string(9) "instagram"
}
```

Global code looks like :

```
$file = file_get_contents('./Temp/socallink.txt', true);
$file = str_replace('"', '', $file);
$a1 = explode(',',$file);
```

Hope this'll help

Comment: Please mark as correct whatever answer worked to clean the feed

Answer (score 1):

Since those are Comma Separated Values (CSV), this would probably be the simplest:

```
$file = file_get_contents('./Temp/socallink.txt', true);
$a1   = str_getcsv($file);
```

Comment: Is this case you better do this
***array_map('str_getcsv', $source_file)***

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php
//fetch the file content
    $file =  file_get_contents('your file path`enter code here`');

 //create an array by breaking the string into array values at the comma ',' point
$a = explode(',',$file);

print_r($a);

//result
// Array ([0] => "Facebook"
// [1] => "Twitter"
// [2] => "Twitter"
// [3] => "google-plus"
// [4] => "youtube"
// [5] => "pinterest"
// [6] => "instagram" )
```

Comment: What about the quotes?

Comment: Please add a description for your answer.